# How to pass an array to a @slot in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use it in my layout and I'm suddenly bump-up with the idea of using the new features of Laravel 5.4 @slot.

Just wondering if passing an array to a slot possible?

```
        @section('SampleSection')

            @component( 'mylayouts.partials.contentheader' )

                @slot('title')
                    Sample Title
                @endslot

                @slot('indexes')
                    Pass array here  // example [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
                @endslot

            @endcomponent

        @endsection
```

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to pass an array to a component via `@slot`. However, it *is* possible to pass and an array to a component directly, without using a slot.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots):

> Passing Additional Data To Components
>
> Sometimes you may need to pass additional data to a component. For
>   this reason, you can pass an array of data as the second argument to
>   the @component directive. All of the data will be made available to
>   the component template as variables:
>
> ```
> @component('alert', ['foo' => 'bar'])
>     ...
> @endcomponent
> ```

So let's say you have an array of data:

```
$my_array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

You can pass it to the component like so:

```
@component('mylayouts.partials.contentheader', ['my_array' => $my_array])
    ...
@endcomponent
```

Or you can just pass it directly, without using a variable:

```
@component('mylayouts.partials.contentheader', ['my_array' => ['a', 'b', 'c']])
    ...
@endcomponent
```

Then, within your component file, you will have access to a `$my_array` variable. For example, in your **`contentheader.blade.php`** file you can do this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($my_array as $value)
        <li>{{ $value }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

I need the same.

This works as a temporally solution, but is not the best form for do it.

```
@component('component.tab.header')
    @slot('navs', [
        "a" => "Pepe",
        "b" => "Maria"
    ])
@endcomponent
```

**EDIT:**

Finally, in my case, I solved doing this:

```
@component('component-name')
    @slot('slot-name')
        Value1|Value2|Value2
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

And in the component code:

```
@foreach(explode('|', $slot-name) as $value)
    The value is {{ $value }} <br/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Actually tried that one but was having difficulty catching the array in the slot views. What I did is put another '@include' inside the '@component' and using a variable parameters for the slot to work. It's not pretty though...

Comment: See my new edit, I thinks this is the more clear-code option.

Comment: I think your original answer is actually the better one. I'm going to try and ask this week in the Slack to see what the intended way is, and hopefully update the documentation after so it is clearer.

Comment: @Ivan - that's precisely what I did in my previous code but I ended up using `@include` instead. I just hope Taylor would add functionality to add variable parameters in `@slot` instead of doing what we just did or there might be better ways to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample component. Assign number of items to `$numberOfSlots` variable and it will search for slot blocks one by one (`body_1`, `body_2`, `body_3`)

Because I build a form wizard and it's too ugly to define html blocks between `" "` so I prefer `@slot`.

**Component:**

```
<div class="component">
    @for($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfSlots; $i++)
        <div class="item">
            {{ ${"body_{$i}"} }}
        </div>
    @endfor
</div>
```

---

**Blade:**

```
@component(['numberOfSlots' => 3])
    @slot('body_1')
            Dynamically created slot 1
    @endslot

    @slot('body_2')
            Dynamically created slot 2
    @endslot

    @slot('body_3')
            Dynamically created slot 3
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Works fine so far, specially for lists

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but couldn't you just pass the data to the component and handle that in the component? Docs show

Sometimes you may need to pass additional data to a component. For this reason, you can pass an array of data as the second argument to the @component directive. All of the data will be made available to the component template as variables:

@component('alert', ['foo' => 'bar'])
    ...
@endcomponent

deal with the data in the component instead of using a slot?

Answer (score 1):

it's so simple and easy send array into component template without any @slot
in view page

*view.blade.php*

```
@component('components.button',[
  'tooltipTitle'=>'buttorr33',
  'addStyle'=>'pointer',
  ])
  @endcomponent
```

in component php file *component\button.php*

```
<div class="block-buttons {{$addStyle or NULL}}"
     {{--if set tooltip, add atributes--}}
     @if (isset($tooltipTitle))...
```

Comment: @Nelson Melicio sending data into view via array, in view must be variable with the same name like key in associative array. `'toolitipTitle'=>'buttor33'` in view file will send it into component which is set at first param. Then in that component file you could use variable with name $tooltipTitle. If it doesn't set it will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

How I do it:

**Include @PageNav component tag in any view**

```
@PageNav([
    'menus' => [
        [
            'title' => 'foo', 
            'url' => '/foo/index'
        ], 
        [
            'title' => 'bar', 
            'url' => '/bar/page'
        ]
    ]
]) @endPageNav
```

**Create view/components/PageNav.php file**

```
@foreach ($menus as $menu)
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ $menu['url'] }}">{{ $menu['title'] }}</a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

**Register the component:** (AppServiceProvider.php -> Boot)

```
Blade::component('components.PageNav'); // "/views/components/PageNav.php"
```

Hope it's help!

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 10** <-- current latest version

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#passing-data-to-components

```
<x-mylayouts.partials.contentheader :title="$title" :indexes="$my_array" />
```

- trailing / means no matching closing tag needed
- this will load */resources/views/components/mylayouts/partials/contentheader.blade.php*